# MacOS vscode open dir via the right mouse button

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, folders, visual-studio-code

There is a way to set the possibility of being able to open a dir on vs code via the right mouse button where the menu appears, as I do with the terminal in this way.

```
code .
```

[image: en]